# Playing 2 videos together in python

Tags: python, python-gstreamer

I would like to play 2 videos together using python. Apart from that, I would like to pause , forward and rewind just 1 video at certain times in other video.
I started implemented this using Python Gstreamer and its possible to play 2 videos together but the second part is complicated. Does any one know python libraries which can do this ?

Thanks a lot, Thothadri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [GStreamer GNonLin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gnonlin/html/) plugins.

Comment: Hey, I started implementing using this. But i am currently facing this problem.( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055018/scheduled-pause-in-gnonlin). Do you have any solution for the same ?